# How can I replace all non-words in a phrase, with the exception of numbers followed or preceded by characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Let us take a ruby array of `sentences`. Within the array we have

1. Sentences containing only words
2. Sentences containing phone numbers
3. Sentences containing numeric values with units of measurement

   - In this case we may have things that look like this: `1mL`, `55mL`, `1 mL`, etc
4. Sentences containing quantities denoted as `1x` or `5 x`.

I am trying to construct a ruby regexp for the `gsub` or `scan` functions, such that I clean up the above `sentences` array to only be left with the words (1), units of measurement (3), and quantities (4) in each sentence, but clean up all non-word characters, such as phone numbers (2) and any other delimiting characters such as `\t`.

I've got this so far:

```
sentences.map do |sentence|
  sentence.gsub!(/(?:(\d+)(?:[xX])|([xX])(?:\d+)[^a-zA-Z ])/, "")
end
```

Unfortunately, that replaces the exact opposite of what I want to replace. And, it doesn't account for cases where units of measurement are what I want to preserve at all.

**Example inputs and outputs:**

**input:**     `Lavender top (6 mL size preferred)`
**output:**   `Lavender top (6 mL size preferred)`

**input:**   `Blood & bone marrow aspirate: 15 mL centrifuge tube with transport media. Available from Cytogenetics, 415-123-4567.`
**output:** `Blood & bone marrow aspirate: 15 mL centrifuge tube with transport media. Available from Cytogenetics, .`

**input:**   `Gold top x1, Lt. Green top x 1, Lavender top x1`
**output:** `Gold top x1, Lt. Green top x 1, Lavender top x1`

***So, effectively, replace numbers and other non-alpha characters, but only when the numbers don't denote measurements or quantities***

I've been playing on rubular for about 3 hours to no avail. I think I might be misunderstanding look-aheads completely or just missing one key gotcha moment.

Looking forward to the regexp experts chiming in!

Comment: Example input and outputs would help a lot

Comment: I've provided examples and further context, as you had asked :) Thanks for the constructive criticism.

Comment: Later, I'll probably want to extract the units of measurement and the quantities :) So, I think that using capture groups would be appropriate.

Comment: this is difficult. unless you know what represents a measurement or quantity. What is the subset of measures and quantities you want to match ie litres (l) metres (m) feet (ft) etc, or does the sample data represent all you need to match

Comment: @gwillie I'll probably have to deal with a data dictionary at some point in the future. For now, let's just assume `mL` or `ml`.

Comment: As far as quantities, let's assume just `xn`, `x n`, or `nx` `n x` for now, where `n` is the number of "items," and may be 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could perhaps be a start:

```
input.map!{|x| x.gsub(/(?<!x\s|x)[\d-]+(?!\s?\w\w?)/i, '')}

#/(?<!x\s|x)[\d-]+(?!\s?\w\w)/i

# (?<!x\s|x) Dont match if after an x or x+space
# [\d-]+ Match digits (and other junk)
# (?!\s?\w\w) Make sure it is not followed by a two letter word. Here you could be more specific if it causes trouble.
# /expression/i make the thing case insensitive.
```

Comment: Isn't `(?<!x\s|x)` like `(?<!x\s?)` ?

Comment: Also, the `x` or `X` may either follow or precede the `n` digits of the quantity measurement.

Comment: You but I think you are not allowed to use questionmarks in look-behinds for some reason. I get `invalid pattern in look-behind: /(?<!x\s?)[\d-]+(?!\s?\w\w)/`

Comment: If the x might follow just ad a question mark at the last \w in the look-ahead. Did an edit.

Comment: @hirolau: You are right, you can use variable length lookbehinds in ruby!

Comment: @hirolau It seems that with the question mark at the end, as you had suggested, patterns like `x123` are not accounted for. In other words, the question mark in the end does not solve the problem quite yet. There are also some other issues:

http://rubular.com/r/bA2Ja1lk1Q

Comment: We are getting into very complicated stuff now and I think it will only be luck to find something that works for all cases. `(?<!x\s|x)[\d-]+(?!\s?\w\w?\s|\d)` works for the case you posted, but i bet you can find some variant it did not take into account. If it is only phone numbers, maybe we could ad a length criteria?

Answer (score 0):

This works on your sample data, but there may be other cases not taken care of:

```
(?<!x\s?)\b[-.\d]+\b(?!\s*?ml)
```

The regex only matches the `415-123-4567` in your sample data.